# Documentation or source code for azure javascript function binding?

Tags: azure-functions

I'm trying to see what is possible with the service bus binding for azure functions (1.x), but I can't find good data.  There are some examples, but what I really want to do is move a message to the deadletter queue if I detect certain errors.

We use the default of 10 delivery attempts and don't want to change that because sometimes there are temporary network errors and we want to retry.  However in some circumstances we find out the data is bad and we cannot process the message until it is fixed.  In this case we want to move the message to the deadletter queue immediately.  Otherwise we will have multiple requests occurring each of the following 9 times.  This generates extra traffic for the services we query and muddies up the logging in app insights.  Also if we want to log these errors or send a message elsewhere we don't want to get ten copies.

Looking at the [reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---peeklock-behavior), they don't really seem to be a reference.  There's a snippet of javacript code that shows the context has a `bindingData` object with some message properties and a `done()` function:

```
module.exports = function(context, myQueueItem) {
    context.log('Node.js ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message', myQueueItem);
    context.log('EnqueuedTimeUtc =', context.bindingData.enqueuedTimeUtc);
    context.log('DeliveryCount =', context.bindingData.deliveryCount);
    context.log('MessageId =', context.bindingData.messageId);
    context.done();
};
```

Other languages have other properties listed in different ways.  Is there a way to tell the function host to send the message to the DLQ?  Is there any real reference to the properties that should be on the context?  Can someone point me to the source code that creates the context so I can see myself?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible in Javascript. There was a similar discussion in this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31958).

This is because of the way other languages work in Azure Functions. The data passed to non-c# functions is serialized during transit, hence losing any native properties it may have had in C#.

In case of C# in Functions v1, you can bind to a [`BrokeredMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage?view=azure-dotnet) object on which you could call the [`DeadLetter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.deadletter?view=azure-dotnet) / [`DeadLetterAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.deadletterasync?view=azure-dotnet) methods. And for Functions v2, you will have to bind to [`MessageReceiver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver?view=azure-dotnet) which isn't documented yet but is mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1986#issuecomment-433960534).